# Animating a unitary transform

Tags: unitary-representations

For the purpose of showing how (quantum) unitary operators behave as a computer animation, I would like to create a function $A_U(t)$ of some (complex) unitary matrix $U$, such that $A_U(t)$ is unitary, $A_U(0) = I$ (identity) and $A_U(1.0) = U$. How can I create such a function? Would it help to have the eigenvectors? (IANAM)

Answer (score 0):

$A_U(t):=\exp(t\log(U))$ where $\exp$ and $\log$ are the matrix exponential and logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

A unitary matrix has the form $U_1 D U_1^*,$ where $U_1$ is unitary, $D$ is diagonal, with entries of modulus $1,$ so of the form $\exp(2\pi i x).$ Make $D(t)$ have entries $\exp(2\pi i t x).$

Comment: I'm confused... How do I derive x and $U_1$ from U, and why do you think this will work?

Comment: I don't think this will work, I KNOW this will work. As for how you get $U_1,$ a unitary matrix is normal, so has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors. $U_1$ is it.

Comment: And, by the way, this is actually the same as the other answer.